# Value of type 'CGPoint' has no member 'makeWithDictionaryRepresentation' in swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, cgpoint

I am working with Swift 3. In my code I am using Siri integration in Wallet App.I am getting an error in that App. I searched in google for it but I didn't find the solution for it.

Here is my code:

```
 func createPath(_ points: NSArray) -> UIBezierPath {
        let path = UIBezierPath()
        var point = CGPoint()

        //CGPointMakeWithDictionaryRepresentation((points[0] as! CFDictionary), &point)
        point.makeWithDictionaryRepresentation((points[0] as! CFDictionary)) // In this line I am getting an error
        path.move(to: point)

        var index = 1
        while index < points.count {

            //CGPointMakeWithDictionaryRepresentation((points[index] as! CFDictionary), &point)
            point.makeWithDictionaryRepresentation((points[index] as! CFDictionary))
            path.addLine(to: point)

            index = index + 1
        }
        path.close()

        return path
    }
```

Here is the error I am getting:

> Value of type 'CGPoint' has no member 'makeWithDictionaryRepresentation'

Can any anyone Please help me resolve it.
 Thanks in Advance.

Comment: error clearly says that `CGPoint` has no member like `makeWithDictionaryRepresentation`. So how you can set or call that ?

Comment: Refer [Apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coregraphics/cgpoint/1455382-dictionaryrepresentation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Swift 3 you need to use init `CGPoint(dictionaryRepresentation:)`.

```
let point = CGPoint(dictionaryRepresentation:points[0] as! CFDictionary)
```

It will return optional `CGPoint` instance so batter to use with `if let` or `guard`

```
if let point = CGPoint(dictionaryRepresentation:points[0] as! CFDictionary) {
     print(point)
}
```

Check Apple Documentation on [`CGPoint`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coregraphics/cgpoint/) for more details.

Comment: @hrithib Welcome mate :) also it is batter if you optionally un wrap to `CFDictionary` using `if let` instead of Force wrapping using `!` it may cause you crash if it is not convert it `CFDictionary``.