# Value of type 'EnumeratedSequence<[CGPoint]>' has no member 'compactMap'

Tags: ios, swift

I want to implement Charts in my project, but when I open demo project I got this error Value of type 'EnumeratedSequence<[CGPoint]>' has no member 'compactMap' I see this [Value of type 'CGPoint' has no member 'makeWithDictionaryRepresentation' in swift 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40925984/value-of-type-cgpoint-has-no-member-makewithdictionaryrepresentation-in-swif) link but error is not resolved.

Comment: Which Xcode version are you using? compactMap was introduced in Swift 4.1 (Xcode 9.3)

Comment: I am Using swift  4.0 (Xcode 9.2)

Comment: Yep; no `compactMap` there. It's called `flatMap`

Comment: so i use flatMap?

Comment: exactly; until you upgrade to Swift 4.1

Comment: Martin i comment that func and my project is running now.I appreciate for help

Answer (score 7):

In Swift 4.0 and older, the `Sequence` protocol has two versions of `flatMap`:

```
Sequence.flatMap<S>(_: (Element) -> S) -> [S.Element] where S : Sequence
Sequence.flatMap<U>(_: (Element) -> U?) -> [U]
```

In Swift 4.1, [SE-0187](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0187-introduce-filtermap.md) renames the second version `compactMap`:

```
Sequence.flatMap<S>(_: (Element) -> S) -> [S.Element] where S : Sequence
Sequence.compactMap<U>(_: (Element) -> U?) -> [U]
```

You are using a version of Charts that has been updated to Swift 4.1, but you are using a Swift 4.0 compiler.

You can:

1. Downgrade to an older version of Charts that only uses Swift 4.0.
2. Upgrade to Xcode 9.3, which supports Swift 4.1.
3. Change your copy of Charts to use `flatMap` instead of `compactMap`.
4. Add a “shim” to your copy of Charts to add `compactMap` (thanks [BasThomas](https://gist.github.com/BasThomas/d03e138a9bb098d347c52ca7d6870a45)):

   ```
   #if swift(>=4.1)
   #else
   extension Collection {
     func compactMap<ElementOfResult>(
       _ transform: (Element) throws -> ElementOfResult?
     ) rethrows -> [ElementOfResult] {
       return try flatMap(transform)
     }
   }
   #endif
   ```